# Como buscar informações do usuário logado sem ser pelo controller?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

Estou utilizando o spring security para fazer o login do meu site. Está funcionando, consigo cadastrar novos usuários, logar e deslogar.

Tenho uma navbar que, quando o usuário não está logado, aparece a opção de "Logar ou cadastrar", e quando ele está logado aparece a opção "Sair".

Porém eu gostaria que exibisse o nome do usuário logado do lado do link de logout, e não estou conseguindo fazer isso:

SecurityConfig:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
        .usersByUsernameQuery(userQuery)
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(roleQuery)
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("senha")
            .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/home");
}
```

Navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark custom"
    th:fragment="cabecalho">
    <a href="/home"><img src="../img/transp_IziFood6.png" class="navbar-brand logo"/></a>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 searchNav" type="search" placeholder="Pesquisar">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
    </form>
    <div th:if="${session.isEmpty()}">
        <div class="divlogin"><a href="/login">Entre </a> | <a href="/registration"> Cadastre-se</a> </div>
    </div>
    <div th:unless="${session.isEmpty()}">
        <div class="divlogin"><a href="/logout">Sair </a></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Como esse navbar é um fragmento, eu gostaria de saber como buscar as informações pelo thymeleaf, para não precisar ficar repetindo código buscando informações do usuário logado em vários controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode recuperar os dados de autenticação através do `SecurityContextHolder` e `SecurityContext`:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

Com o objeto `Authentication`, você pode recuperar os dados do `Principal` autenticado através do `getPrincipal()`. Existem outros métodos para recuperar authorities, credenciais, verificar se ele está logado...

Detalhes podem ser vistos [aqui](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html), [aqui](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html#getAuthentication--) e [aqui](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html)

Comment: Esse comando consigo executar no thymeleaf?

Comment: Sim, você pode criar um service que contenha este código e referenciá-lo em seu fragment